# get total from recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object which have reference to its collection

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'A',
    referer_id: null,
    point: 4
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'B',
    referer_id: 1,
    point: 100
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'C',
    referer_id: null,
    point: 4
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'D',
    referer_id: 1,
    point: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'E',
    referer_id: null,
    point: 4
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'F',
    referer_id: null,
    point: 4
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'G',
    referer_id: 2,
    point: 4
  },
];
```

the referer id will refer to the id. And I have another array of number used to calculate the point

```js
const pointsByLevel = [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]; // this would be dynamic from database
```

as of now, I can get the sum of all total like this

```js
function getPoint(user_id) {
  const mainUserPoint = data.find((u) => u.id === user_id).point;
  let sum = 0;
  
  for (let subdep of data.filter((d) => d.referer_id === user_id)) {
    sum += getPoint(subdep.id);
  }
  return mainUserPoint + sum;
}
```

but the real challenge is the first level should return the point only but afterward the point will be multiplied to `pointsByLevel` based on the index

so the output will be like this

```js
console.log(getPoint(1));
/**
A - 4
B D - [100 * 0.5], [2 * 0.5]
G - [4 * 0.3]
**/

// 4 + 50 + 1 + 1.2 = 56.2
```

So the end result I'm gonna get 56.2

What is the most efficient way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to keep track of how many levels deep you are as an additional argument to `getPoint`.  Set the default to 0, and the increment it each time you recurse.  You can then find the corresponding points by level for it.  (I inserted a 1.0 coefficient for level 0).  I also added a comment to show the partial results at each level.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'A', referer_id: null, point: 4 },
  { id: 2, name: 'B', referer_id: 1, point: 100 },
  { id: 3, name: 'C', referer_id: null, point: 4 },
  { id: 4, name: 'D', referer_id: 1, point: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: 'E', referer_id: null, point: 4 },
  { id: 6, name: 'F', referer_id: null, point: 4 },
  { id: 7, name: 'G', referer_id: 2, point: 4 }
];

const pointsByLevel = [1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2]; //  NOTE: I added a 1.0 for level 0

function getPoint(user_id, level = 0) {
  const user = data.find((u) => u.id === user_id);
  const mainUserPoint = user.point;
  let sum = 0;

  for (let subdep of data.filter((d) => d.referer_id === user_id)) {
    let val = getPoint(subdep.id, level + 1);
    sum += val;
  }
  let result = (mainUserPoint * pointsByLevel[level]) + sum;
  console.log(`getPoint for ${user_id} "${user.name}" is ${level} levels deep and has the value ${result}`)
  return result;
}

console.log(getPoint(1));
```

Comment: this is nice but is there any other way without having to intervene the `pointsByLevel`

Comment: Of course.  You could substitute `pointsByLevel[level]` with `(level ? pointsByLevel[level-1] : 1)`  or you could index `[1, ...pointsByLevel][level]`